# How to turn off recording in motioneeyeos

Tags: networking, picamera

So, i got 2 questions at the same time.
I'm using a pi 4 4Gb with 64SD card running motion eyeos

Changed settings to 1080p@30fps codec to h264. and motion triggered to continuous recording
When I open the browser i see that the camera is already recording which seems very obious, however if it is recording it's also continuous writing to a file.

How am I supposed to download that file when it is being written or at leas(t when there is a filestream open?

What i do now is I just plug out the power cord and put it back in so a new recording start however this is a bad habbit as some of my recordings are corrupt so that something I do not want.
So is there a way to stop and start recordings in motioneyeos and or a setting to split file every 3GB for example?

Comment: Please ask only one question in a Question. If you have two questions then create two Questions. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: i know how things work i have accounts on many other stackexchange forums but i'll edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using continuous recording just set a specific length for the video. Motioneyeos gives you the option (in seconds if i remember rightly) to continuously record but start a new file every x seconds. For my setup I use continuous recording with a 300 second  time limit which splits the recording into 5 minute clips.

Comment: there seems to be another problem so i set it on 600seconds so 10min but after the first file it stops recording? there is no red square anymore an no more files either any idea or another setting i'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what red box you're talking about. With my motioneye installs there's no indicator that tells you its recording and if you've got the recordings switched on then it just records and the files are whereever you set the path for them. You'd have to look at the logs and see if anythings showing in there.